# 100.0% usage by Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek

Tags: cpu, powertop, codecs

I ran powertop, and it says that the Realtek audio codec is using 100.0% of the cpu. Is this a problem?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit on Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 640 @ 2.80GHz × 4 Sony VAIO laptop.

Comment: It says that it's **active** 100% of the time, not that it uses 100% of the CPU. ;) I don't see it causing any trouble here.

Comment: you can enable power saving mode on the audio speaker using powertop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it just means that you have (probably digital) sound output enabled. If you have some sound outputs, such as digital (optical/coaxial) or hdmi you are not using, then you can blacklist their drivers and you might save some battery. They will be listed in `lsmod` something like, **snd_hda_code_realtek** and **snd_hda_codec_hdmi**. By adding these to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` you can disable them.

Comment: In case someone finds this question looking for a way to remove the realtek audio from Powertop **DO NOT FOLLOW THE ABOVE ANSWER**. Blacklisting the drivers will disable all audio from your machine. The only way to fix it is to remove the blacklisting and then doing a hard shutdown with `sudo sh -c "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger"`. **USE THE ANSWER BELOW THIS ONE**

Answer (score 27):

Try changing "Enable Audio codec power management" to good in the Tunables tab for powertop. After doing so, hwC0D0 is no longer listed in powertop for me.

Comment: It worked for me too (now let's see if power consumption will improve). 
Anyway there are loads of other settings like this one, I've enabled all of them...cross fingers the system will boot the next time :)

Answer (score 7):

I found that muting the microphone input in the mixer solved the problem.  I use a Dell XPS17.

Comment: This mean your microphone was constantly listening?

Comment: Looks like it works only one time. The 100% usage disappeared after I muted mic, but when I turned it on for a while, and turned it off again, 100% usage stayed intact.

Answer (score 0):

Muting / disabling stuff with alsamixer helped me get rid of the same problem on macbook air.