# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, modprobe

Please note that I have tried all solutions in the below two links:

["Dummy Output" sound in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460035/dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-14-04)

[No Sound card detected in Sound Settings, although sound works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155178/no-sound-card-detected-in-sound-settings-although-sound-works)

`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` does not solve the problem

`pacmd list-cards` shows `0 card(s) available.`

When the sound was working fine on my 18.04 before, I tried to modify  `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` in order to solve a different issue following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91368/719469). But after my sound stop working I removed the added lines which blacklisted the drivers. Could this have caused my problem?

Please help me out, I cannot work without sound on my PC for long

**Update**:

Since I have Dual Boot on my PC, I booted into Windows in which also the sound was not working, the Windows troubleshooter couldn't identify the problem so I went in Device Managers and **reinstalled the Realtek HD Audio Controller**, It didn't solve my problem, the sound still wasn't playing but a remarkable thing that occured was when I booted back into Ubuntu 18.04, it detected a Built-in Audio

and now `pacmd list-cards` shows :

```
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1428000 irq 128"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9d70"
    device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Despite detecting this 1 card now, I am still not being able to get any sound, please help out

Comment: I am having [an almost identical problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132026/dummy-output-listed-as-sound-device-in-18-04), only on Lenovo Thinkpad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install music packages of `rhythmbox` and `amarok` with:

```
sudo apt install rhythmbox amarok
```

or if they are already installed then:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall rhythmbox amarok
```

As I know these packages have some more drivers.

Then reboot.

Sorry, because of package amarok. That was earlier days of Ubuntu.

You could then try following :

> sudo apt install rhythmbox clementine

or

> sudo apt install --reinstall rhythmbox clementine

(improved answer 10th July 2020)

Comment: I didn't have the music packages of rythmbox installed and seems like the drivers in these packages may have solved the issue. Thank You!

Comment: @KewalShah - good to know, that answer was of good use.

Comment: I was having some static noise on my HP envy when I installed ubuntu 18. Your answer has actually reduced the frequency of the static noise.

Comment: @PhillipMwaniki - About different noises I dont have any clue. Am deaf here. But nice, if this thread is of help.

Comment: That's ironic. For once the word actually applies!

Comment: this didn't work for me -- using Lenovo Thinkpad

Comment: `E: Package 'amarok' has no installation candidate`

Comment: it works for me, but the sound comes out of the main speakers even when I set the output device to headphones. Also, none of the playback devices work when I test them in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of not having any sound device detected, so no sound at all after updating ubuntu from 16. to 18.04

I searched for some solution and, to be honest, what I tried was kind of a compilation of some answers found, so I am not sure which one was the real solution.

What I did and found the sound working was:

sudo alsa force-reload

killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*

then rebooted *but* before loading ubuntu, I made a quick pass from the other OS installed in dual boot, that is Windows 7, as this was a solution that worked for some other pal, so after one more reboot, sound is back.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Ubuntu 19.04, everything was good. After several updates, there is no sound anymore. I googled and tried many solutions, but there was no luck. I came across a post which mentions installing ubuntu restricted addons.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

This command resolves my issue.

But under Firefox, Youtube still has no sound. It is another issue. @@

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem and I had tried everything but I couldn't resolve the problem. Then I figured out that it wasn't the driver causing the problem it was keyring password that I had provided.

So if you have tried everything, try to reset your keyring password to blank.

1. Go to **System > Preferences > Password and Encryption keys**
2. Right click the appropriate folder
3. Click Change Password
4. Put in your old password and leave the new one blank

and if it doesn't work and u have installed chrome remote desktop app

There is some problem with chrome remote desktop with Ubuntu. Getting back your system sound for all applications you should remove the extension from chrome and ubuntu both.

Run command
     apt remove chrome-remote-desktop or apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop
and restart your ubuntu

Comment: Passwords and encryption do not have anything to do with sound problems.