# ASUS VivoMini UN65U: can't get audio from analog jack

Tags: sound, kubuntu, alsa, asus, phonon

I have just installed Kubuntu 18.04 on an ASUS VivoMini UN65U without any problem except I can't use the usual audio minijack as an output.
In Phonon configuration I only have the option to output through HDMI1 to HDMI4, no analog output.

`aplay -l` too lists only HDMI1 HDMI2 HDMI3 HDMI4 outputs.

How do I make the analog audio output jack work?

EDIT: solved just by keeping the system dist-upgraded in the following weeks.

Comment: Still not working? I am unfamiliar with Kubuntu, but I wonder, if you could try Pulseaudio and pavucontrol?

Comment: Now it works, I don't know why. Maybe the issue was just solved with some update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was fixed by installing the `rhythmbox` and `amarok` packages, which seem to have the drivers bundled for device audio to stay on for good.

Try running:

`sudo apt install rhythmbox amarok`

[Referencing this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook/1042327#1042327).