# Why cannot I hear any sound?

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus

Brand new laptop Asus X542UA and installed `Linux Mint`. Sound is not working and I have no idea what the problem is. Can you point me in the right direction. There is no error or anything. Should I reinstall a different distro?

UPDATE: [result from `sudo lshw -C sound`]

```
*-usb:2                   
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
       vendor: Azurewave
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 16.08
       serial: 0x0001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:131 memory:ef328000-ef32bfff memory:ef300000-ef30ffff
```

I checked `pavucontrol` and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: Perhaps missing drivers for your sound card. Something similar -
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: You haven't provided us with any information, and other distro's are off-topic here (*just a note that discourages us in answering anyway when you go off-topic!*).  Is your sound card recognized?  (`sudo lshw -C sound" or list-hardware category sound).  Have you looked in `pavucontrol` (pulse audio volume control) to ensure it's not been disabled by a keystroke from you (*happens to me semi-regularly on some keyboards*)

Comment: Will get back with the info. Trying Linux mint now to see if there's any difference