# "Dummy Output" listed as sound device in 18.04

Tags: sound

Since several days ago (something automatically upgraded), I get no sound out of my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. I tried several things other similar threads suggested:

> pacmd list-cards

returns 0 cards

> lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

returns nothing, and

> pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

and rebooting does nothing.

How do I get my sound back?

Also -- this seems like a fairly huge defect -- does anyone know what happened in `apt-get upgrade` to have caused this?